# Do the angels in Ezekiel 1:10 represent the 4 aspects of creation according to evangelicals?

Tags: heaven, creation, angels, symbolism, ezekiel

Ezekiel 1:10 tells of the heavenly creatures with the faces of humans, eagles, lions, and oxen:

> As for the likeness of their faces, they four had the face of a man,
>   and the face of a lion, on the right side: and they four had the face
>   of an ox on the left side; they four also had the face of an eagle.  -
>   Ezekiel 1:10

In John MacArthur's introduction summary of the book of Ezekiel he explains them as angels `"representing aspects of creation over which God rules"`
as quoted here:  http://www.gty.org/resources/bible-introductions/MSB26/ezekiel

My question is, if they do, what 4 aspects of creation do the faces represent?

Comment: According to who? This will be very opinion based.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This question is off-topic and does not fit into one of the [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409) If possible, [edit] this question so that it better fits into one of those question types.

Comment: I think it is clear in the question that the "according to who" is John MacArthur or other fellow evangelicals.

Comment: @fredsbend I stated the question in a way that is less assumptive.  I hope this works.

Comment: @AffableGeek Okay, I retracted vtc. Gave a +1 too.

Comment: Evangelicals is still very broad. Why do you think they would agree? This would be better suited on Hermeneutics where multiple answers can be given with their own arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Ezekiel’s Vision is essentially divided into three main parts, according to [this Bible study from a Baptist source](http://www.founders.org/ss/explore/060505.htm):

> 1. Ezekiel’s Vision of the Lords Glory (1:10-28)
> 2. The Prophet’s Commission and the Hardships He Would Encounter (2:1-10).
> 3. The Prophet’s Message (3:1-27).

And the intention of the vision can be viewed as the following, [according to Matthew Henry](http://www.apostolic-churches.net/bible/mhc/MHC26001.HTM):

> 1. To possess the prophet's mind with very great, and high, and honourable thoughts of that God by whom he was commissioned and for
>      whom he was employed
> 2. To strike a terror upon the sinners who remained in Zion, and those who had already come to Babylon, who were secure, and bade defiance to
>      the threatenings of Jerusalem's ruin, as we have found in Jeremiah's
>      prophecy, and shall find in this, many did.
> 3. To speak comfort to those that feared God, and trembled at his word, and humbled themselves under his mighty hand.

So the question remains, "what 4 aspects of creation do these faces represent?" Matthew Henry says:

1. Lion: Strength and Boldness
2. Ox: Diligence and Patience
3. Man: understanding of a man and much more
4. Eagle: Quickness as well as an uplifting of angels over men

Comment: Welcome to the site! This doesn't really have much to do with the quality of your answer, but I find that sharing the following tends to help new visitors avoid mistaking the purpose of this site. I do hope to see more from you! When you get a chance, please see [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Comment: Hey thank you for the information =) I'll try my best to follow your recommendations!